# Will AutoIncrement work with Check constraints?

Tags: sqlite, auto-increment, check-constraints, check-constraint

The question is simple:
In SQLite, if I choose to AutoIncrement a primary key of type `NUMERIC` which has a check constraint like `CHECK(LENGTH(ID) == 10)`, will it work correctly inserting the first value as 0000000001 and so on?

Comment: Probably not, since you tried it. You did try it?

Comment: No I didn't try. I never used SQLite and I am planning with an ER model first. That's why I asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to restrict the value of an autoincrement column like that, you need to seed the internal sequence table. (There are other ways.)

```
create table foo (
  foo_id integer primary key autoincrement,
  other_columns char(1) default 'x',
  check (length(foo_id) = 10 )
);

insert into sqlite_sequence values ('foo', 999999999);
```

> Application code is allowed to modify the sqlite_sequence table, to
>   add new rows, to delete rows, or to modify existing rows.

[Source](http://www.sqlite.org/fileformat.html#seqtabd)

```
insert into foo (other_columns) values ('a');
select * from foo;
```

```
1000000000|a
```

Trying to insert 11 digits makes the CHECK constraint fail.

```
insert into foo values (12345678901, 'a');
```

```
Error: CHECK constraint failed: foo
```

One alternative is to insert a "fake" row with the first valid id number immediately after creating the table. Then delete it.

```
create table foo(...);

insert into foo values (1000000000, 'a');
delete from foo;
```

Now you can insert normally.

```
insert into foo (other_columns) values ('b');
select * from foo;
```

```
1000000001|b
```

Answer (score 2):

No, that does not work. Adding a check does not magically also add a way of fullfilling the check to insert the data.

See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/c517b).

Answer (score 0):

In fact the ID's length is 1, so it doesn't work.